# Behaviour of match %in%

Tags: r

I feel like I've been trained to negate by putting a bracket around the logical condition that I want to negate.

But I recently saw something that works without the brackets when I really didn't expect it to.

```
x <- "a"
y <- letters[1:3]
!(x %in% y) # Negate is x in y? I've been trained to do this. FALSE
x %in% y # Is x in y? TRUE
!x %in% y # Negate x is it in y? FALSE
```

That last result returns FALSE, but isn't it say `negate x and match y` rather than match x in y and negate.

Has something changed with this syntax that suddenly makes it unnecessary to type the brackets for the purpose of negation?

```
!(x %in% y) # FALSE 
!x %in% y # FALSE, but feels like it's correct by coincidence.
```

Comment: Interestingly, when I look at other peoples code from older questions, I see everyone using the brackets when negating.

Comment: `## but we strongly advise to use the "!( ... )" form in this case!` @Henrik I wonder if their reasoning was the same... style clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code has order of operations, much like regular algebra. In R, the `%operator%` operators are listed to be of higher precedence and are therefore essentially evaluated before the `!` negation operator. Here is a reference: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html

Therefore, `! a %in% b` is the same as `!(a %in% b)` by the laws of R's syntax evaluation/parsing rules, even if it looks different.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen It's probably a matter of style and convention, meant for clarity. This is a good thing as well, as it *looks* wrong but still does the right thing. If it makes you feel mentally uncomfortable, it's because the code you've seen is clear enough to follow this logical convention.